# Handling empty HTTP response with Glimpse

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

I'm integrating Glimpse to a legacy production application (Upgraded to MVC3). Most pages have a lot of ajax requests and some of the ajax requests return an empty response based on the business logic.

Glimpse client fails to parse such empty responses (out of may be 20-30 responses). Chrome console clearly shows where it fails.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of null Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_client&hash=0a37c827:3633
display.ajax.processContentType Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_client&hash=0a37c827:3633
display.ajax.update Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_client&hash=0a37c827:3657
display.ajax.XMLHttpRequest.open
```

The reason is that the processContentType function is given a 'null' as contentType (variable named 'type' within the function) and the following statement fails.

```
return type.substring(0, type.indexOf(';'));
```

What bothers me is the fact that the whole Glimpse window does not show up (Glimpse icon is not hyper-linked to open up the Glimpse tabs) as a result. Is there anyway (configuration?) to workaround the issue?

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a bug report more than a question. Would you mind reporting this on [the Glimpse Issue Tracker](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues)?

Comment: Done. https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by updating Glimpse to 1.5.0.

---Here's the comment from Glimpse;

> avanderhoorn commented 6 hours ago
>   You must be running an old version of Glimpse.core. This was fixed with PR #401 (reported in
>    #400) and went live in release https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/releases/1.5.0.

All I did was 'Update-Package Glimpse' in VS package manager console and it's fixed now.